# World of Warcraft sub cards

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So I have the starter edition of wow and have been playing this way for about 6 years well I finally have enough money to buy the game. I know that sub cards can be used for game time and to first buy the game but my question is, can they be used to buy the expansion? I want to but the digital deluxe version of legion and don't want to go through the hassle of trying to put money in a PayPal then risk that getting hacked and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game time cards are for game time only. If you want the Digital Deluxe Edition you'll have to pick one of the payment methods provided by the Blizzard store. Retail copies are available for the base game and normal edition of Legion. So you'll have to choose from:

- Direct Debit (if your region and bank support it)
- Giropay (dito)
- Credit card
- PayPal
- Battle.net Balance*

[*] Battle.net Balance can be bought with the same payment methods. However, it is confirmed to also get the possibility to add BNet balance by buying WoW Tokens off the auction house in an upcoming patch. So you could buy the game with ingame currency.
**Note:** This is not yet possible, but it will be added soon.

If you can't or don't want to use either of these payment methods you should **buy the normal Legion edition in a normal store**. Blizzard has made the Digital Deluxe items of Warlords of Draenor available for purchase, so it's possible to get the Legion extra items sooner or later as well.

You can as well ask a trustworthy person to make a trade. They can gift you the game (buy with their account and gift it to you through the Blizzard store) and in exchange you give them game time cards worth that amount.